# How to draw rullar in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone

Hi I want to make rullar in iphone.
Que: How to draw lines through `UILabel` in `scrollView` 1 inch. or 1 cm. apart from each other.
I know there are 163 pixels per inch(ppi). in 480-by-320-pixel.
But I am not sure about all version of iPhone .

Does the size of pixels are same for all its model???

Comment: Unless he means rullar, the Swedish hard candy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing in iOS uses point values rather than pixels; in a retina display there are four pixels (2x2) in a point and in a non-retina display there is one. The screen sizes are the same (with the obvious exception of the iPads). If you draw a line from (0,0) to (0,100) it will be the same length on the screen of the iPhone 4 and iPhone 3GS.